# Fputc doesn't work in if else

Tags: c++, c, file, file-io

I want to change one value of a file, but the follow code doesn't work at all. It works properly when i remove the if statement.
Code follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int b;
    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("new", "r+");
    fseek(fp, 0x30, 0);

    b = fgetc(fp);
    if(b == 0x63)
        fputc(0x64, fp);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

file "new":
c111111111c1111111111111111111111111111111111111c1111111111111111111

Is there some details that I don't know？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written one *past* `b` if it is `0x63`, because `fgetc` advances the file stream:

```
b = fgetc(fp);
if(b == 0x63) {
    fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    fputc(0x64, fp);
}
```

Comment: You are good, it works.But why the character next to [b] was not been changed when i didn't seek back? it should have been changed, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your problems is, fp = fopen("new", "r+");
"r+" is to read and append. If you're trying to overwrite data, then that won't work. Also, fgetc advances the file stream as stated before.

Comment: Actually "r+" is ok for overwriting data, others like "w" or "w+" will clear the current file.

Comment: That's interesting, it didn't work for me when I tried. I specifically tried to overwrite the data I had in a file. It would only let me append.